# HTML how to set value of <input type="number"> to infinity

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, infinity

I have a number input that I want to hold integers. If the value gets set to negative then I want the symbol shown to be ∞ (`&#8734;`).

Doing this doesn't work (a blank is shown instead of "∞"):

```
<%
if foo <= -1
    v = '&#8734;'
else
    v = foo
end
%>
<input type="number" value="<%= v %>">
```

Is there a way to do it without resorting to javascript?

Comment: <input type="number" value="&#8734;"> works for me

Comment: @juvian and what browser would that be?

Comment: Firefox. Just tried in chrome and it stays blank as you say

Comment: Do you need the input to be type number? Would work if you set it to string

Comment: FF 28 simply displays '&#8734;' as a string in the input field. Chrome is blank, yes. Setting value to '1234' as a string sets the value appropriately on both browsers. juvian, your solution works but only on FF and only if the code is entered into the value field directly (string doesn't work). I need a solution that works for Chrome though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are your requirements for having a "number" field? Can you rely on form validation and use Javascript to progressively enhance just typing numbers. Then use something like this

```
<input type="text" pattern="([0-9]|&#8734;)+">
```

(`pattern` will prevent the form from submitting unless it's a number or infinity symbol)

Comment: This is interesting, but &#8734 doesn't work in the regex... I'm looking into getting it to though.

Comment: the pattern needs to be `&#8734;` and using `raw v` is necessary when setting value: `<input type="text" pattern="([0-9]|&#8734;)+" value="<%= raw v %>">` This works on both Chrome and FF for showing the infinity symbol. Now, for extra points, is there a way to reject alphabetic characters and not allow them to be typed into the input at all?

Comment: forgot the semi-colon, but added. Does that not work? I just tried it in a blank HTML and seems to validate. 

`<form action="#"><input type="text" pattern="([0-9]|&#8734;)+" value="&#8734;" /><input type="submit" /></form>`

Comment: To prevent the input you'll probably have to use Javascript, but it's called "progressive enhancement" for a reason :). 
What would be the impact of users being able to see letters in there if they have JS off?

Comment: Alternatively, could you keep the `type="number"`, then use `pattern` regex to invalidate any number thats not positive (`pattern="[^0-9]+"`), then use css ":invalid" pseudo-class to add the infinity symbol as a background image?

Comment: oops.. that was meant to be `<input type="number" pattern="^[0-9]+">`. Oh but `type="number"` doesn't prevent text input does it? derp..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use type `text` for this field and convert infinity sign using `CGI::unescapeHTML`

```
<% 
   if foo <= -1
     v = CGI::unescapeHTML('&#8734;')
   else
     v = foo
   end
%>
<input type="text" value="<%= v %>">
```

Answer (score 0):

this question is a bit old, but if anyone else has the same problem, this was my solution, it's a bit janky, but it works:

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" value="&#8734">

<script>
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("focus", (e) => {
    e.target.type = "number";
});
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("blur", (e) => {
    if(e.target.value == 0 || isNaN(e.target.value)){
        e.target.type = "text";
        e.target.value = "∞";
    }
});
</script>
```

[You can check a codepen here](https://codepen.io/levyks/pen/LYWWLgK)

The good thing about this approach is that the user can still use the arrows to increase/decrease the number, since the type is still "number"